# Invoke-sqlcmd doesn't return data in rows

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

The Invoke-Sqlcmd doesn't return data in rows, it lists each item separately

This is the code that I'm using:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyServer" -Query "SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]"
```

I get something like this:

```
Key         : 81839
Type        : DELETE
TableName   : InstList
ColumnName  : Key
ID          : 1092110700485
OldValue    : 5216268
NewValue    : 
UpdateDate  : 7/22/2019 12:06:30 PM
UserName    : test
FeatureName : Instruments

Key         : 81840
Type        : DELETE
TableName   : InstList
ColumnName  : Key
ID          : 2101128532011
OldValue    : 5289370
NewValue    : 
UpdateDate  : 7/22/2019 12:06:30 PM
UserName    : test
FeatureName : Instruments
```

Why does it not come out in rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does it not come out in rows?

It is only  matter or presenting data:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyServer" -Query "SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]" 
| out-gridview
```

or:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyServer" -Query "SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]" 
| Format-Table -AutoSize
```